# How can I prevent an app (specifically zoom) from running in the background when I close it?

Tags: notification-area, background

When I close a certain app (Zoom) it appears in my notification area and continues to run as a background process. I have to manually right click and exit the program (or open task manager and exit) each time. How can I prevent it from running as a background process and force it to automatically shut down completely when I close the program?

Note:
It doesn't appear in settings>privacy>background apps. I already checked that.

Comment: Its how the app is coded, nothing you can do to change the behavior imho.

Comment: Here is a Workaround: Instead of closing the zoom window, right-click on the taskbar icon and select "Quit Zoom". In the Zoom settings, you can uncheck "When closed, minimize window to the notification area instead of the task bar". Like this, Zoom will never run acidentally in the background, but you will always see from the taskbar if it is still open or not.

Comment: thanks for the workaround! hope they fix their shit or someone else helps come up with a better solution.

Comment: Every other answer than killing the process is application specific (I do not use zoom myself btw), so it would be nice to put zoom in the subject of your question.

Comment: This is dangerous in this day and age, especially if a session is still live and you are unaware of it.

Comment: For Zoom Specifically, they hide it well but there is a webclient and so you do not need the app at all. The best way to avoid getting the app  launched is to uninstall it, then if you are using Chrome, you can install the Zoom Redirector extension that will automatically switch Zoom links to the webclient, so that you don't have to jump through hoops every time

Comment: The people who create these apps need a proper UX person to help them out. The minimize icons purpose is to minimize things. It is frustrating as hell when these morons remap a close button to minimize the thing, and do away with the minimize button.

/rant.

Zoom please hire some UX people so you can design your app properly

Answer (score 8):

This annoys me too, so I wrote a oneline AutoHotKey script for this:

```
^q::run, taskkill /f /im zoom.exe
```

This does the following:

- `^q` means control + q. You can change this to another shortcut if you like, I'm just used to using this already for closing programs.
- `run,` runs the following command in a CMD shell.
- `taskkill` lets us kill the specified process.
- `/f /im zoom.exe` means to force close the process called zoom.exe.

If you're new to AHK, you can use the snippet in the following way:

1. [Download and install AHK](https://www.autohotkey.com/download/).
2. Save the above script into a file with an `.ahk` extension.
3. You can [add the script to your startup folder](https://www.howtogeek.com/208224/how-to-add-programs-files-and-folders-to-system-startup-in-windows-8.1/) (or add a shortcut to it) so it will run in the background when you start your computer.
4. Just remember to ctrl+q when you're done with zoom to close it :)

Comment: This is great. I find it useful not to accidentally close an ongoing meeting so here is an alternative `SetTitleMatchMode, 1
if Winactive("Zoom") && !Winexist("Zoom Meeting")
    run, taskkill /f /im zoom.exe
Else 
 WinClose A` ; asks whether you want to leave the ongoing meeting

Comment: This is fantastic. Zoom drives me nuts with how it obnoxious it is with keeping it's windows always on top with no option to disable, refusing to minimize meetings and instead shrinking the always on top window, going full screen automatically when someone else decides to share their screen, and not quitting when you tell it to. Now I have the satisfaction of killing zoom quickly and easily :)

Comment: @Giesbrecht There's an option in the zoom settings to disable full screen on share: Zoom client -> settings -> share screen -> window size when screen sharing (i set it to maintain current size). Killing zoom is still satisfying hehe.

Answer (score 2):

I put together a script that will close zoom (if it isn't in a meeting) when <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F4</kbd> was pressed or to close it outright if <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>F4</kbd> was pressed, both shortcuts still work normally if zoom isn't the selected window.

```
;Alt + F4 (will close zoom if it is the selected window except during a meeting)

$!F4::
if WinActive("ahk_exe Zoom.exe")
    {
    if WinExist("Zoom Meeting")
        {
        return
        }
    else
        {
        Run cmd.exe /c taskkill /F /IM zoom.exe,, hide
        }
    }
else
    {
    send !{F4}
    }
return

;Alt + Ctrl + F4 (will close zoom if it is the selected window)

$!^F4::
if WinActive("ahk_exe Zoom.exe")
    {
    Run cmd.exe /c taskkill /F /IM zoom.exe,, hide
    }
else
    {
    send !^{F4}
    }
return
```

I have also compiled the above script into an executable file, this allows it to work even if you don't have AutoHotKey installed.

[Download it Here.](https://github.com/TheDimensionofEternity/Close-Zoom-with-AHK)

Answer (score 0):

The only reliable way to do this is:

1. Remember which specific apps have this "always minimize to system tray when user closes window" and instead of closing the window, mouseover the systray icon, click and select Exit.
2. Automate the above process with AutoHotKey or similar (beyond my abilities).
3. Write a background Windows 10 app to allow administrator to disable a list of programs from running in the background, alt. always exit application when user clicks the X to close a window.

Answer (score 0):

It's an ad hoc solution, but it may be helpful for you. You click the Close button, AutoHotKey kills the zoom process. The position pixel numbers 2, 78 and 43 are for my PC, you may need to adjust them to your PC.

For people you don't know AutoHotKey, download it [here](https://www.autohotkey.com/) and install. Then, make a text file with "quit-zoom.ahk" or something like that and paste the code into it. You can put the ahk file in the Windows startup folder.

```
#IfWinActive, ahk_class ZPPTMainFrmWndClassEx 
~LButton::
  CoordMode Mouse, Window
  MouseGetPos MX, MY
  WinGetPos, WX, WY, WW, WH, A
  X := WW - MX 
  Y := MY
  if (X > 2 && X < 78 && Y > 2 && Y < 43) {
    Sleep, 500
    Process, Close, zoom.exe
  }
  Return
#IfWinActive
```

Answer (score 0):

An alternative solution. This one does not rely on mouse coordinates but responds to the Windows "Close" message:

```
#IfWinActive ahk_class ZPPTMainFrmWndClassEx

~LButton::
    CoordMode, Mouse, Screen
    MouseGetPos, X, Y, HWND
    if !(HWND = WinExist("Zoom Meeting")) {
        SendMessage, 0x84,, (Y << 16)|X,, ahk_id %HWND%
        if (ErrorLevel = 20)
            Process, Close, zoom.exe
    }
return
```

Answer (score 0):

As someone said - we can create work around, but Zoom designers thinking that 'X' means run in background is a flaw.  They should have atleast given the user a choice to select "exit" or "run in background" in settings.

In a similar tone, I hate when program installation thinks that a shortcut on desktop should be created...

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://superuser.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://superuser.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/1107914)